# Русский язык в запросах PDO PHP

Tags: pdo, php

Здравствуйте!

Как можно "включить" поддержку русского языка при выборке данных из таблицы базы данных?
Пробовал :

```
 ...
 $ps = $db->prepare("SET NAMES utf-8");
 $ps->execute();
 ...
```

Но ничего не вышло! В самой базе данных данные отображаются нормально, будь то русский язык или даже китайский. Но при выборке данных и последующем отображении на страницу выводятся знаки вопроса...что делать, ребят?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"mysql:host=**;dbname=**;charset=utf8"
```

Будет работать с php > 5.3.6

Всё же есть в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

Comment: А вот за это реально большое спасибо! Помогло! За native-линк отдельное спасибо...

Comment: а вот у меня не работает)

Comment: @MartinezToni а база случаем не UTF-16? если нет, то создавайте новый вопрос с пометкой, что вот это решение не работает.