# Русский язык в PDO php

Tags: php, pdo

Подключение к БД выполнено так:

```
"mysql:host=**;dbname=**;charset=utf8"
```

В php файле прописано:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'utf8');
```

Данные в базе:

```
utf8-general-сi
```

И все равно получаемые из базы данные (язык русский) отображаются в виде знаков вопроса

Comment: какая кодировка самой базы данных?

Comment: utf8-general-ci

Comment: Тип innoDB у полей тоже utf8-general-ci

Comment: а как данные попадают в БД? этим же скриптом?

Comment: Нет, данные уже были в базе. База взята из старого проекта просто для изучения PDO

Comment: [не ваш случай?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132149/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-pdo-php)

Comment: Попробовал записать в базу с помощью этого подключения, записывает кракозямбы. Maxim нет не тот случай

Comment: @Алексей а в какой кодировке сам PHP-файл?

Comment: UTF-8 пишу в PhpStorm

Answer (score 3):

Указываем кодировку при коннекте с базой, причем кодировка должна быть utf8mb4:

```
$this->connect = PDO("mysql:host=;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, мне тоже помогло. Нигде больше этого точно нет.
Только я вставила просто `;charset=utf8` в строку: `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mybaza;charset=utf8", "myname", "myparol");`